# How to search in autocomplete in label and description

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-autocomplete

Hi I am using jquery autocomplete and is working fine, but i want the autocomplete search to work on both label and desc is this possible, and how can it be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I change the source after every keypress and after that i use the search with empty string for displaying all the list.

```
$(myControll).autocomplete("option", "source", result);
$(myControll).autocomplete("search",'');
```

Thanks for the try Timothy (I didn't test your solution so I don't know if it function or not)

Answer (score 0):

This is quite a problem. I tried to do what you asked but it seems impossible. The only way i can think of doing it would be to actually change the jquery autocomplete code. Downloading the latest version of the code i can see where it searches it. Look for the **filter** function at line 420.

Try changing this (at line 423)

```
return matcher.test( value.label || value.value || value );
```

to this

```
return matcher.test( value.label || value.value || value.desc || value );
```

And that should do it. By adding in the description to the options it should work. I don't have the time to test this but best of luck. Maybe you should ask jQuery to add it as a feature. It wouldn't be very hard for them.

Answer (score 0):

Use a [remote datasource](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#remote). Then you can perform the search against any database fields you like and return the appropriate matches.